# PhoneGap/Cordova, Ripple Emulator, CORS & JSONP

Tags: cordova, jsonp, cors, ripple

Attempting to use the Ripple Emulator to test a PhoneGap application. We're making requests to the server and receiving:

ERROR:

> cordova :: XMLHttpRequest :: setRequestHeader does not work with JSONP.

- a) CORS is enabled on the server and the client
- b) The requests work in the browser
- c) The requests work on the mobile device
- d) I enabled the "Allow access to file URLs" in the settings for the Ripple Chrome Extension.
- e) I launched chrome with the flags:

> --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files

Does Ripple Emulator support CORS httprequest or only jsonp?

If it supports a call from more than just JSONP then I could use some assistance on implementation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ripple Emulator does support CORS httprequest but you need to host your html page as a website on your machine and access it using `http://localhost/yourvirtualdir/yourfile.html` .

Comment: Thank's @Whizkid747 - you are right. I set up a virtual host and accessed it via that local virtual host and it now makes the request.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting up a virtual directory or IIS entry, use PHP's built-in development web server.  This works in Windows and Linux environments.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

Now you can open your browser and navigate to `http://localhost:8000` and your site\app will be served up.  Then you can enable Ripple on that URL.